# Can we restore the files that were removed by a reset if they are staged?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-add

In general, we can restore all the objects that are stored as commits even if they are reset by using `reflog`. As I understand it, this is because they work with the git objects present in the `.git` directory. So, is it possible to restore files if they are staged? Since, blobs will be created for the files when they are staged.

**DETAILED EXPLANATION:** I have made several changes to my repository and I have staged them. Now, I wanted to remove the unstaged changes but instead I reset the entire repository thereby losing all the changes made. I want to recover only the staged changes.

When I staged the files blogs would have been created..will it be possible for me to find out the blobs and recover them(the changes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, likely, technically the changes are still there. The only problem that they're only known by their hashes (which you don't know, obviously). So without a known reference, even "weak", such a reference from `reflog` you don't have a method to pick them up. So, my guess, you can't resurrect them anymore, sorry.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was afraid of